# How can I efficiently stabilize a set of images?

Tags: image, image-processing, cluster-computing, video-processing, image-stabilization

I regularly record data at 30 Hz for one hour at a time (over 100,000 frames). I am recording an object that moves around minimally (less than a hundred pixels). Each frame is stored as a .tiff file.

I'm trying to efficiently generate a "stabilization matrix." For example, if the image has shifted two pixels to the left and one pixel up, then I want to generate a matrix with a row as:

[2, 1]

to signify that image needs to be shifted 2 units on the x-axis, and one unit on the y-axis. Each row in the matrix would represent the necessary "shift" in this way.

Is this possible? I am open to using any language or platform. I also have access to a cluster at my university. I've been passed down a code that's written in Matlab, but it takes about 12 hours to run. I'm hoping to find a more efficient solution. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show a couple of frames? Do you have any fixed points of reference in your images?

Comment: Is your question how to find the shift? You could use features such as SURF or SIFT to detect correspondences between images.

Comment: or just use the centroid of the object ... against the first frame ... without example image is hard to recommend something ... btw you should compute subpixel precision for this to enhance precision...